# Best Practices/Toolsets for Rendering Very Large Meshes in the Browser

Tags: three.js, 3d, visualization, mesh

WARNING: Admittedly broad questions so I appreciate any help offered since I know SO usually likes more specific questions.

I'm new to the space of 3D rendering in the browser. I'd like to be able to render very large meshes (10s of millions of vertices/faces) with ability to annotate on the mesh with meta data as well as selectively show//hide multiple textures on the mesh. While I read through the literature (e.g. https://danielhaehn.com/papers/franke2020modern.pdf), I'm looking for general advice on the best tools for a beginner to use to address a project like this.

So far, I've put together a small working example using next.js + 3DHOP (which uses the Nexus.js) to render a model that has 31 million triangles and 62 million faces. This is great, but, as hinted earlier, I'd like more functionality than 3DHOP provides out the box along with the ability to render multiple textures/meta-data annotations.

Is modifying 3DHOP the way to go or would it be better to construct something separate more from the ground up just using tools like three.js (I assume this would need to use Nexus.js for effective LOD'ing/efficient streaming)?

Some of the meshes are essentially maps rendered from imaging scans, so I've considered Cesium.js as a possibility too. However, at present I don't need these maps to be rendered geospatially w.r.t. each other or a globe so I'm assuming three.js is the better choice of the two?

From my reading thus far, it seems that streaming frames (perhaps from Unity to the browser) would likely be inferior to using tools like three.js/WebGL/Nexus.js that use native rendering client side. While I'm curious how this would even work, is this an accurate assessment?

What are the recommended tool-sets for the task of rendering large meshes in the browser with ability for meta-data annotations and versatility to offer selectively rendering textures with other functionality like distance measuring, etc.?

Thanks!